# updating dataset when adding a new field in database in c#

Tags: c#, database, dataset, datasource

I have made a database and created a table with five fields and used add new datasource  and added a new dataset by using that. And I have made a form and inserted all fields by dragging them into the form and changed lots of the properties.  Now I need to add a new field into the table in database. Do I have to create a new datasource and a new dataset and do everything from beginning or there is a way to update the datasource and dataset so that the new field automatically appears in them?
Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: You can update your data source after you add the new column in the database (assuming that by data source you mean a data model).

Comment: Question is not clear enough. I'm not sure if You want to update database after updating your dataset in your application or You want to update Your dataset after updating database ?!

Comment: I had added a new column to one table in my database. But in does not appear in the dataset in the corresponding datatable. What can I do to see that column in the dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/95d5b943-3641-4955-acac-287d21760d4f/how-to-update-dataset-xsd-in-vs?forum=winformsdatacontrols) you should right-click the TableAdapter in the Dataset Designer and click 'Configure' the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard opens where you can reconfigure the main query that defines the schema of your table. This should leave the additional TableAdapter queries (the additional methods) that were added after initial configuration.

So follow these steps

1. Open you xsd file.
2. Right click on `Fill,GetData` -> Configure
3. Click `Query builder` and add the new column in the query statment
4. Click `ok` and then your dataset is updated with the new database structure

If it doesn't work try deleting the dataTable and drag your table from Server Explorer again in your xsd file

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is the column name that I added to the database and I want to add it to dataset does no appear in the Query Builder Pane in the table columns. I can only see old columns.

Comment: try to write the column in the query and let me know

Comment: I did so but I saw this error Message: Invalid column name 'mobile'. 'mobile' is the column name that I added.

Comment: right click on your server explorer on your specific dataConnection then press "refresh"

Comment: Is there any way that I can Update dataTable so that the column name appear in the dataTable?

Comment: I did so but nothing has changed. Still the column name does not appear in the dataTable.

Comment: can you consider the option to remove the datatable from your xsd and re-add new one updated?

Comment: I did but still nothing is changed. It does not appear in the DataTable.

Comment: i think that it's impossible! if you drag and drop your refreshed table into the xsd are you able to see the new column?

Comment: I did not use drag and drop.I updated the whole database in dataserver pane and I just went through wizard. I removed the dataTable and I created it again but the column name does not appear in the DataTable.

Comment: try with drag and drop from  server explorer

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it did work. But at first i used data source pane to create the  new data source and the table adaptors and data Tables were created automatically. And then I used drag and drop from Data source pane and put all the fields on the form automatically and the field were connected to the corresponding textboxes on the form. What can I do to update the columns in data source pane? and then use drag and drop to put all field names on the form automatically? By the way thank you so much.

Comment: if my answer solve your problem remembar to mark my answer as accepted to avoid that the question remains unanswered

Comment: I think that now it is connected to your database and if you add a new column then following my first part of the answer you'll see the new column

Comment: you should click on a tick on the left of my answer